# Textbook recommendation on Inverse Problem Theory

Tags: numerical-methods, book-recommendation, machine-learning, inverse-problems

I am looking for a textbook on inverse problem theory, which includes both **Regularization and Bayesian approach for inverse problem solving, including data assimilation, preferably machine learning aspects of it included (but not strictly needed)**. **I want the focus on applications and coding, with bare minimum focus on mathematical definitions and theorems.** I am currently reading Nakamura and Potthast's Inverse Modeling (link is [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/book/978-0-7503-1218-9)) and my eyes are completely glossing over the ton of mathematical details present.

Comment: For theory, my recommendation would have been the Regularization of Inverse Problems book by Engl, Hanke and Neubauer. In your case, maybe check the books by Hansen on the subject or possibly the one of Vogel; they are more applied and "hands on".

Comment: Kress's "Linear Integral Equations".

Comment: Vogel's "Computational Methods for Inverse Problems" gives a nice overview of the theory (it does not have machine learning). It's nice and short, but it is pretty mathy.